# Ubuntu server,node.js imagemagick svg to png encoding

Tags: node.js, encoding, svg, imagemagick, png

I am in a project,that convert svg to png in the server side----node.js server.So I use imagemagick and the the server install imagemagick 6.7.7 also install the libsvg2-bin.Everything works well but the text encoding problem.The server use UTF-8 but failed to convert.

```
require("fs").writeFile(target_path_svg, svg, [], function(err) {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err);
        return;
    } else {
        im.convert([target_path_svg, 'png:-'], function(err, stdout) {
            if (err) {
                throw err
                res.send("error");
            }
            fs.writeFileSync(target_path, stdout, 'binary');
            res.send("ok");
            return;
        });
        return;
    }
});
```

anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, pass `target_path` as the second parameter in the array in the call to `im.convert()` (instead of `png:-`). It will directly write the file.